# LINQ query returning no results

Tags: c#, linq

I run the following `LINQ` query so that I can see a table of two columns, but I cannot see the result in a `DataGrid` can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
Database d = server.Databases[cboDatabases.SelectedItem.ToString()];
System.Data.DataSet ds = d.ExecuteWithResults("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS");  
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];             
MessageBox.Show(dt.Columns.Count.ToString());  
var query = from data in dt.AsEnumerable()//AsEnumerable()
            select new
            {
                TableName = data[0],
                FieldName = data[1]
            };
dataGridView1.DataSource = query;
```

Comment: need to use ToList() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `ToList` on your query, to fetch results:

```
var query = from data in dt.AsEnumerable()//AsEnumerable()
            select new
            {
                TableName = data[0],
                FieldName = data[1]
            };

dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```